# Open facebook page url in Facebook app if available

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk, url-scheme

Its a game app. There are multiple levels. In each level we have different fb page urls. The url is uploaded at server and it can vary at times. How do I open the urls in the facebook app if available rather than in browser? I tried openURL() but it opens in browser.

Comment: Can you open pages in app using urls?use webview control instead of browser... you can show within app if you need